# Integrate HDFS in Red Hat OpenShift or in the Infrastructure?

Tags: integration, hdfs, openshift

I have a cluster of five virtual machines (with KVM hypervisor), and I want to find the best way to integrate HDFS in order to optimize storage management of Data.

Since HDFS is a distributed file system that can allows client to access in parallel to a file, I want to take advantage of this feature.
So, it is possible to install HDFS in the cluster to manage the disk space of VMs or to integrate it in OpenShift to manage data of PaaS end user?

Answer (score 0):

If you are thinking of using this with OpenShift Origin or OpenShift Enterprise then you can just expose the HDFS to the OpenShift nodes as a user disk space and they can use it. Remember when you install OpenShift on your own infrastructure you can expose any file system you want as long as you can normally do it for Linux users.